# Where should PHP write sessions to?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

Just installed PHP 5.4 on Centos 6.4 with Apache 2.2 VPS, and received an error that permission is denied to open session.  php.ini shows `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"`.  Do I make `/var/lib/php/session` permission 0777?  Or maybe make Apache run as a given user, and then give that user rights to `/var/lib/php/session`.  I recall in the past changing session path to `/tmp`, and wonder if that is a better strategy.  Where should I set PHP to write sessions to?

Comment: Had you changed the user apache runs as before testing, as you answer, centos should have had it run as apache, and had proper permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of flexibility and - even more importantly - security, you should configure the Apache to run the scripts (read: php-processes) as another, unprivileged user per vhost using suEXEC + FCGId or something similar. Then you can assign a own php.ini for every user and set the session path to a user-only writable path (for example in the users */home* directory). There're plenty of tutorials for this common setup, just search for *"centos apache suexec php"*

This might be the most complex solution to your problem, but it also takes security and some flexibility for the future into account.

Answer (score 2):

Make Apache run as user/group apache/apache.  CentOS will automatically have permissions set correctly for `/var/lib/php/session`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mod_fcgid` then the apache user won't be usable as a `/var/lib/php/session` user/group owner.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions should be stored with Memcached.

```
session.save_handler = memcached 
session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```